# OracleDataAdapter Fill method hangs

Tags: c#, oracle, web-services

I am writing a web service in C# that needs data from a database.

Here's a code snippet I am using:

```
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, connection);
OracleCommand command = adapter.SelectCommand;
AddCommandParameters(ref command, objParams);
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("TableName");
adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
```

The debugger hangs (infinite time) at the `adapter.Fill` command, without throwing any exception.
Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong? The SQL query works if I use it outside of the web service.

Comment: Ensure the parameters `objParams` are in correct format.

Answer (score -1):

If it's hanging that means there is issue with connection string. Could you please post your connection string.

Also could you please check what is the Platform target for your project under Properties -> Build, try to change it from 'Any CPU' to x86. Your Oracle driver might be 32 bit.